# Narrow text area in chapter opener

Tags: koma-script, chapter-page

I would like to change the chapter opening page. Set up a narrow block of text and place the chapter name in the wide inner margin. I'm using the "koma-script" class.

Page example

```
+--------------+--------------+
|              | title  xxxxx |
|              |        xxxxx |
|              |        xxxxx |
|              |        xxxxx |
|              |        xxxxx |
|              |        xxxxx |
|              |        xxxxx |
+--------------+--------------+
```

---

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{multicol}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt]{chapter}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\chapter{Introduction}
\vfill\null
\columnbreak
\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

It's a simple but satisfying solution. Can I automatically change the layout of page 2 to one column?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. This is not a "do it for me" site.

Comment: If the chapter title will always fit in one line, you need to measure the width.  You can use paracol or flowfram to create uneven columns, but in either case you will need to manally break the paragraph at the end of the page (e.g. \framebreak).

Comment: I am not too familiar with the KOMA classes, but using the `geometry` package, it should be possible to change the left margin of the first page of a chapter so that the text area only has the width of one column so to say. You would then just need to place the chapter title in a box and shift it to the left.

Answer (score 2):

Switching automatically to two-column mode and placing the chapter heading to the left column is not the main problem. Even switching back to one-column mode after the chapter page is not the real problem:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterindent=false,style=section]{chapter}
\newif\ifafterheadingnewpage
\AddToHook{cmd/@afterheading/before}{\ifafterheadingnewpage\newpage\afterheadingnewpagefalse\fi}
\AddToHook{cmd/chapter/before}{\twocolumn\afterheadingnewpagetrue}
\AddToHook{shipout/after}{\onecolumn}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

But as you can see:

[image: not what you want]

the real problem is, that TeX does not change the width of a paragraph, that already has been typeset and that is partly (or even completely) moved to the next page. So you need to spit such paragraphs yourself into the part, that fits to the chapter page, and the part, that should be printed onto the one-column page, e.g.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt,afterindent=false,style=section]{chapter}
\newif\ifafterheadingnewpage
\AddToHook{cmd/@afterheading/before}{\ifafterheadingnewpage\newpage\afterheadingnewpagefalse\fi}
\AddToHook{cmd/chapter/before}{\twocolumn\afterheadingnewpagetrue}
\AddToHook{shipout/after}{\onecolumn}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-2]

Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec
felis erat, congue non, volutpat at, tinci-
dunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fer-
mentum felis. Donec nonummy pellentes-
que ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit.
Proin fermentum massa ac quam. Sed diam
turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie
nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia. Nam ipsum
ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit
{\parfillskip0pt\newpage}%
\noindent
a, ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat ma-
gna. Nunc eleifend consequat lorem. Sed
lacinia nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque tin-
cidunt purus vel magna. Integer non enim.
Praesent euismod nunc eu purus. Donec
bibendum quam in tellus. Nullam cursus
pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi. Nam vulpu-
tate metus eu enim. Vestibulum pellentes-
que felis eu massa.

\lipsum[4-7]
\end{document}
```

[image: this is what you want, but with manual break]

Note: Using the hooks `cmd/<cmdname>/before` and `shipout/after` needs a more or less up-to-date LaTeX.